# C# json deserializing objects

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I tryed deserialize simple json file:

```
{
    "field1_Class1":100,
    "field2_Class1":500,
    "field3_Class1":500,
    "field4_Class1":500,
    "field5_Class1":500,
    "field6_Class1":500,

    "field1_Class2": 200,
    "field2_Class2": "String1",
    "field3_Class2": "String2",
    "field4_Class2": "String3",
    "field5_Class2": "String4"
}
```

If all of these fields would be fields of a Сlass3, it's would be simple to deserialize it like this:

`Class3 p = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Class3>(content);`

But i have this structure:

```
public class Class1
{
    int field1;
    int field2;
    int field3;
    int field4;
    int field5;
    int field6;
}

public class Class2
{
    int field1;
    String field2;
    String field3;
    String field4;
    String field5;
}

public class Class3
{
    Class1 field1;
    Class2 field2;
}
```

So, if i have two json files, i can parse every class (Class1 and Class2) in very easy way. But i have one json file and this structure, and i don't know how parse it in true easy way.

> My english not very good, so be tolerant. Thanks.

Comment: You could always create a new class which reflects the JSON structure, and then write a `ToClass3` method to convert it to the representation you want elsewhere...

Comment: You can also first deserialize it into a `Dictionary<string, object>` and then have methods which parse out the proper classes.

Comment: To create classes, select your JSON sample data and, in Visual Studio, go to Edit / Paste Special / Paste JSON As Classes.

Answer (score 2):

It might be better to separate json into the 2 parts, in order to reduce parameters in the constructor.

```
public Class3(string json)
    {
      field1 = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<Class1>(ResolveJsonPart(json, 1));
      field2 = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<Class2>(ResolveJsonPart(json, 2));
    }

    private string ResolveJsonPart(string json, int fieldNumber)
    {
        // Here  resolve json file 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to define a new class:

```
public class Class3Buffer
{
    field1_Class1

    ...

    field1_Class2

    ...

    public Class3 ToClass3()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

What is unpleasant here is that after you do that you will have to make sure that if in the future any of Class1, Class2 or Class3 change Class3Buffer reflects those changes. You could achieve this in several ways:

- Use some unite test based on reflection that parses the metadata of these classes and ensures they are in sync.
- Use something like T4 templates to auto-generate these classes.
- Generate Class3Buffer as a pre-build step based on reflection.

Another solution is to generate Class3Buffer at runtime dynamically and based on reflection of Class3. That is only if the run-time environment you have allows you dynamic code generation.

Comment: To create classes, select your JSON sample data and, in Visual Studio, go to Edit / Paste Special / Paste JSON As Classes.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution by experiment.

```
public class Class3
{
    Class1 field1;
    Class2 field2;

    //Constructor wich can solve my problem
    public Class3(int f1, int f2, int f3, int f4, int f5 .....)
    {
        field1 = new Class1(f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6);
        field2 = new Class2(f7, f8, f9, f10, f11);
    }
}
```

I think, it's not a "true way", but all my class are immutable and they constructor need to take all parameters. And even if Class3 doesn't have any int or string fields, it normall deserialize json to object.

P.S.
If you know another (true and simple) way - please post answer!

Answer (score 1):

Try -

```
public class RootObject
{
    public int field1_Class1 { get; set; }
    public int field2_Class1 { get; set; }
    public int field3_Class1 { get; set; }
    public int field4_Class1 { get; set; }
    public int field5_Class1 { get; set; }
    public int field6_Class1 { get; set; }
    public int field1_Class2 { get; set; }
    public string field2_Class2 { get; set; }
    public string field3_Class2 { get; set; }
    public string field4_Class2 { get; set; }
    public string field5_Class2 { get; set; }
}

var type = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(new StreamReader("jsonPath").ReadToEnd());
```